# Retrieve Items in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Say I have this knowledge base:

```
step('pancakes', 1, 'mix butter and sugar in a bowl', [butter, sugar], [bowl]). 
step('pancakes', 2, 'add eggs', [eggs], []). 
step('pancakes', 3, 'mix flour and baking powder', [flour, baking powder], []).
```

How do I make a predicate that retrieves all the ingredients for all the steps of the recipe?

So if I would make a rule `retrieveIngredients(X,Y).` and ask `retrieveIngredients('pancakes',Y).`, how would I be able to make it retrieve `Y = ['butter','eggs','flour', 'baking powder'].`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using `findall/3`:

```
retrieveIngredients(R,Y):-
    findall(A,step(R,_,_,A,_),Y).

?- retrieveIngredients('pancakes',Y).
Y = [[butter, sugar], [eggs], [flour, baking_powder]]
```

If you want to get the list flattened, add a call to `flatten/2`. If you want to remove duplicates, add a call to `sort/2`. Note that you need to rewrite `baking powder` as `baking_powder` (without space) in the third `step/5` fact.

Comment: "... `baking_powder` (without space)" or enclose it in single quotes, `'baking powder'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you happen to know how you would add them to the list without them being lists? So instead of [[butter, sugar], [eggs], [flour, baking_powder]] It would just be [butter, sugar, eggs, flour, baking_powder]. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ^^ he statet it: use flatten/2