# Splice in sublists in a list, without using flatten/2

Tags: list, prolog, concatenation, flatten

I want to make one list of multiple sublists without using the `flatten` predicate in Prolog.

This is my code:

```ml
acclistsFromList([],A,A).
acclistsFromList([H|T],Listwithinlist,A):-
  not(is_list(H)), 
  acclistsFromList(T,Listwithinlist,A).
acclistsFromList([H|T],Listwithinlist,A):-
  is_list(H), 
  append([H],Listwithinlist,Acc2), 
  acclistsFromList(T,Acc2,A).
```

I get this as output

```ml
?- listsFromList([1,2,[a,b,c],3,4,[d,e]],X). 
X = [[d, e], [a, b, c]] ;
```

But I want this:

```ml
?- listsFromList([1,2,[a,b,c],3,4,[d,e]],X).
X = [a, b, c, d, e] .

?- listsFromList([1,[],2,3,4,[a,b]],X).
X = [a, b] .

?- listsFromList([[[[a]]],b,c,d,e,[f]],X).
X = [f, a] .

?- listsFromList([[[[a]],b,[c]],d,e,[f]],X).
X = [f, a, b, c] .
```

What is the best way to reach this result, without using `flatten`?

Comment: In your `acclistsFromList([H|T],Listwithinlist,A):-not(is_list(H)), acclistsFromList(T,Listwithinlist,A).`, you do not do anything with `H` after verifying that it is not a list.

Comment: you can just use your own flatten predicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059827/8080648

Comment: edits must not invalidate existing answers, it is forbidden by the SO rules. please don't do this again. by posting on SO you gave it the license for the contents forever, you can't take it back. any further attempt at defacing the post will be reported to moderators.

Answer (score 4):

The second clause of the `acclistsFromList/3` does not do anything with `H` if it has verified that `H` is not a list, but you need to prepend the result with `H`.

```
acclistsFromList([H|T], Listwithinlist, [H|A]) :-
    \+ is_list(H),
    acclistsFromList(T, Listwithinlist, A).
```

but this is not sufficient. Since you prepend to the accumulator, the result is reversed. You do not need an accumulator here anyway:

```
acclistsFromList([], []).
acclistsFromList([H|T], [H|A]) :-
    \+ is_list(H),
    acclistsFromList(T, A).
acclistsFromList([H|T], Result):-
    is_list(H),
    append(H, Res1, Result),
    acclistsFromList(T, Res1).
```

or without the "scalar" elements:

```
acclistsFromList([], []).
acclistsFromList([H|T], A) :-
    \+ is_list(H),
    acclistsFromList(T, A).
acclistsFromList([H|T], Result):-
    is_list(H),
    append(H, Res1, Result),
    acclistsFromList(T, Res1).
```

This furthermore does *not* recurse on lists. A list of lists of lists will thus not be flattened. I leave it as an exercise to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a one-liner,

```ml
foo(X,L) :- 
  findall(Z, (member(A,X),is_list(A),member(Z,A)), L).
```

(as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64919078/849891)).

To deal with multi-layered nested lists, we need to use a recursive predicate,

```ml
nembr(Z,A) :-    % member in nested lists
  is_list(A), member(B,A), nembr(Z,B)
  ;
  \+ is_list(A), A=Z.
```

then use *it* instead of that final `member` call in  `findall`'s goal:

```ml
bar(X,L) :- 
  findall(Z, (member(A,X),is_list(A),nembr(Z,A)), L).
```

testing:

```ml
10 ?- foo([1,2,[a,b,c],3,4,[d,e]],X).
X = [a, b, c, d, e].

11 ?- bar([1,2,[a,b,c],3,4,[d,e]],X).
X = [a, b, c, d, e].

12 ?- bar([1,2,[a,b,[[[c]]]],3,4,[d,e]],X).
X = [a, b, c, d, e].
```

Comment: Yes my solution does something else. I deleted it to think about if for the night.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer it just doesn't skip over the non-lists in the top-level. the first version of the other answer also didn't. :) btw I think doing it by hand as in your code might be preferable, has potential of not being that uni-directional as this approach, in this answer.

Comment: Thanks Will. I will pick it up later. Need to do real-life stuff...

Comment: Well, I finagled something. This too much longer than expected.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to roll your own, here's *breadth-first* enumeration of arbitrarily nested lists:

```ml
bfs( XS, L) :- bfs( s(z), [XS|Q], Q,  L, []).

bfs( z, _, _, Z, Z).
bfs( s(N), [[]   |P], Q,  L, Z) :- bfs( N, P, Q,  L, Z).
bfs( s(N), [[A|B]|P], Q,  L, Z) :-
  is_list(A)                                     % if is_list(A), 
  -> Q = [A|R], bfs( s(s(N)), [B|P], R,  L, Z)   % then      enqueue A, 
  ;  L = [A|R], bfs(   s(N),  [B|P], Q,  R, Z).  % otherwise produce A
```

The first argument is the distance between read and write point on the queue. When they meet the queue has become exhausted and we stop. Both the input queue and the output list are maintained as difference list pairs of head and tail variables.

Trying it out:

```ml
12 ?- bfs( [[[6]],1,2,[4,[[[[[7]]]]],5],3], A).
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] .
```

You will need to augment it to skip the non-lists in the top level.

Comment: That's really compact. Using Peano numbers instead of integers also allows one to perform matching directly in the head as well as subtraction & addition inline. That's a very good idea. Never thought of that. The negated `is_list/1` can be made positive, right?

Comment: had simple integers there at first. was hoping it'll become deterministic, with the Peano... but it makes  for shorter code anyhow. yeah we can just flip the order of branches.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that uses an "open list" to append the elements encountered while walking the list-of-lists, which is essentially a tree, in prefix fashion.

The indicated examples indicate that non-list elements at depth 0 shall be discarded, and the other elements sorted by depth. However, no precise spec is given.

Indeed, one would expect the result of flattening

`[[[[a]],b,[c]],d,e,[f]]`

to be

`[b,f,c,a]`

via the "sorted-by-depth" pair list of Depth-Value pairs:

`[3-a,1-b,2-c,1-f]`

But the question poster requests this result instead:

`[f, a, b, c]`

I don't really know whether this is an error or not.

```
:- debug(flatwalker).

flatwalker(ListIn,ListOut) :-
   Tip=Fin,                            % 2 unbound variables
   %                                   % designating the same memory
   %                                   % cell. Hold the Tip, grow at Fin.
   flatwalker_2(0,ListIn,Fin,TerFin),  % Elements are appended at Fin.
   %                                   % The final Fin is found in TerFin
   %                                   % on success.
   TerFin=[],                          % Unify TerFin with [], closing
   %                                   % the list at Tip.
   keysort(Tip,Sorted),                % Sort the closed list at Tip
   %                                   % by pair key, i.e. by depth.
   %                                   % keysort/2 is stable and keeps
   %                                   % duplicates.
   debug(flatwalker,"Got : ~q",[Tip]),
   maplist([_-V,V]>>true,Sorted,ListOut). % Remove depth values.

% ---
% flatwalker_2(+Depth,+TreeIn,+Fin,+TerFin)
% Depth:  Input integer, indicates current tree depth.
% TreeIn: The list to flatten at this depth (it's a node of the tree,
%         which may or may not contain subtrees, i.e. lists)
% Fin:    Always an unbound variable denoting the end of an open list to
%         which we will append.
%         ("points to an empty memory cell at the fin of the open list")
%         Works as an accumulator as a new Fin, advanced by 1 cell at each
%         append operation is handed to the next flatwalker_2/4
%         activation.
% TerFin: When flatwalker_2/ is done, the final Fin is unified with 
%         TerFin so that it can be passed to flatwalker/2.
% ---

% We make the guards explicit and cut heavily.
% Optimizing the guards (if so desired) is left as an exercise.

flatwalker_2(_,[],Fin,Fin) :- !.       % Done as TreeIn is empty. 
                                       % Unify Fin with TerFin.

flatwalker_2(0,[X|Xs],Fin,TerFin) :-   % Case of X is nonlist at depth 0:
   %                                   % discard!
   \+is_list(X),!,
   flatwalker_2(0,Xs,Fin,TerFin).      % Continue with the rest of the
                                       % list at this depth.

flatwalker_2(D,[X|Xs],Fin,TerFin) :-   % Case of X is nonlist at
   %                                   % depth > 0: keep!
   D>0,\+is_list(X),!,
   Fin=[D-X|Fin2],                     % Grow the result list at its
   %                                   % Fin by D-X.
   flatwalker_2(D,Xs,Fin2,TerFin).     % Continue with the rest of the
                                       % list at this depth.

flatwalker_2(D,[X|Xs],Fin,TerFin) :-   % Case of X is a list at any
   %                                   % depth.
   is_list(X),!,
   DD is D+1,
   flatwalker_2(DD,X,Fin,Fin2),        % Collect one level down
   flatwalker_2(D,Xs,Fin2,TerFin).     % On return, continue with the 
                                       % rest of the list at this depth.
```

Some [`plunit`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) tests:

```
:- begin_tests(flatwalker).

test("empty",true(Out == [])) :-
   flatwalker([],Out).

test("simple",true(Out == [])) :-
   flatwalker([1,2,3],Out).

test("with empties",true(Out == [])) :-
   flatwalker([[],1,[],2,[],3,[]],Out).

test("test 1",true(Out == [a, b, c, d, e])) :-
   flatwalker([1,2,[a,b,c],3,4,[d,e]],Out).

test("test 2",true(Out == [a, b])) :-
   flatwalker([1,[],2,3,4,[a,b]],Out).
   
test("test 3",true(Out == [f, a])) :-
   flatwalker([[[[a]]],b,c,d,e,[f]],Out).

test("test 4",true(Out == [f, a, b, c])) :-
   flatwalker([[[[a]],b,[c]],d,e,[f]],Out).
   
:- end_tests(flatwalker).
```

And so:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: flatwalker 
% Got : []
.
% Got : []
.
% Got : []
.
% Got : [1-a,1-b,1-c,1-d,1-e]
.
% Got : [1-a,1-b]
.
% Got : [3-a,1-f]
.
% Got : [3-a,1-b,2-c,1-f]
ERROR: flatwalker.pl:66:
        test test 4: wrong answer (compared using ==)
ERROR:     Expected: [f,a,b,c]
ERROR:     Got:      [b,f,c,a]
 done
% 1 test failed
% 6 tests passed
false.
```

Comment: I think to agreeably comment Prolog code, one needs special editor support. Commenting Prolog is important!

Comment: I have a distinct memory of talking with the OP in the comments (after the first version of the question when the example list shown was only one level deep), and her telling in the end that the order is not important.  the order as presented in the question is inconsistent anyway. but your idea that it is actually breadth-first is interesting. ---- starting reading your post I thought you did a proper breadth-first enumeration, but you've cheated! :) by using keysort. so it is still not that pure version which I had hopes for... :)

Comment: @WillNess Sounds like a case for "iterative deepening". Or ... can I use continuations?

Comment: just [a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60561480/849891). :) (ignore all the Haskell there) (it's about binary trees, but the general idea is the same, I think) btw I sense a bit too imperative an attitude in your comments/code; I had that too, in that Q&A, and it made it harder for me to find the solution, and in the end it wasn't the most fitting one. (you can read around there to find out more.)

Comment: oops, it's about creating a tree from its bfs enumeration, i.e. the *opposite*. there's a code for enumeration there too, in the answer, but it's in Haskell. (or maybe it'll work in both directions?? ....)

Comment: i've added another answer here with the bfs. it's not pure enough though, I don't think...

Comment: @WillNess It's hard to be non-imperative when you grow a term at its leaves. Or is it?